# How to delete old data points from graph after 10 points?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am plotting my data using chartist and I am updating the chart dynamically but the chart is not looking good as it is appending values over and over. I want to remove the first array element as the 11th array data appends.

Basically I only want to show only 10 points in the screen. How I can do this? I am using python flask for web programming and data is coming from arduino and using the chartist library.

Here is the JavaScript used.

```
var mychart;
var now = new Date().getTime();
var getdata = $.get('/a');
getdata.done(function(r) {

   var data = { 
      labels: [
       ],  
      series: [ 
         r.r
       ]
     }; 

    var options = {
       width : 1200,
       height : 300 
    }  
    mychart = new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data, options);
});

var myupdate = setInterval(updatechart,1000);
function updatechart() {
    var updatedata = $.get('/a');
    updatedata.done(function(r) {
        var data = { 
           labels: [
            ],  
           series: [ 
              r.r
            ]
        }; 

        mychart.update(data);
    });
}
```

Here is my python code. Where i am reading the continuous data from arduino.

```
from flask import  Flask, render_template,request,redirect, url_for,jsonify
import flask
from shelljob import proc
import time
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
from flask import Response
import serial
from time import time,gmtime,strftime
from datetime import datetime
import json

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
lj= serial.Serial( '/dev/ttyACM0' ,9600)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('dynamic2.html')

v=[]
@app.route('/a')
def a():
    if (lj.inWaiting()>0):
        mydata= lj.readline() 
        v.append(mydata)    
        print mydata

    return jsonify({'r':v})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to use the first 10 returned items, so you should change

```
r.r
```

to

```
r.r.splice(r.r.length-10)
```

so you always retain the last 10 elements

But that'll only help in the client side. If you're not going to use more than 10 elements in the client, then you shouldn't send them from the server. It that the case, you should change

```
return jsonify({'r':v})
```

to

```
return jsonify({'r':v[-10:]})
```

so you'll only send the last 10 items to the client

If you're not going to use more than 10 elements on the server either, then you should change

```
v.append(mydata)
```

to

```
v.append(mydata)
if len(v) > 10
  v.pop(0)
```

this way, each time you append a new item to the list, and it gets over 10 items, you delete the first one

For your other question (how to put current time in x axis) you should send the time from the server. Since you already imported time, you could do it like this

```
v={'r':[],'t':[]}
@app.route('/a')
def a():
  if (lj.inWaiting()>0):
    mydata= lj.readline() 
    v['r'].append(mydata)
    v['t'].append(time.time())    
    print mydata
  return jsonify(v)
```

I haven't really used the Chartist library, but a quick browse through [its examples](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html) tells me that's what the `labels` property is there for. So you should update your Javascript to this

```
updatedata.done(function(r) {
  var data = { 
    labels: r.t,  
    series: r.r
  }; 
  mychart.update(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Piyin. It is working now !! One more thing How can i add current time in x axis ?

Comment: Thanks again @piyin but when i run the code it throws error "dict object has no attribute r "

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'm really used to Javascript... You can't access a dictionary with `.property`, instead, you should do `['property']`... I updated the code